# File size difference in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

When I read file size using st_size, I am getting 11264 bytes:

```
k = os.stat(r"C:\Users\sakth\Desktop\ASRS.txt")
print(k.st_size)
```

But when I read the file in chunk and sum up their bytes, I am getting only 11060 bytes.

```
fp = open(r"C:\Users\sakth\Desktop\ASRS.txt", 'r')
total_bytes = 0

while True:
    chunk = fp.read(1024)
    if chunk == '':
        print("File reached EOF")
        break
    print(chunk)
    total_bytes = total_bytes + len(chunk)

print("total bytes sent", total_bytes)
```

Why is a different size for the same file obtained?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on Windows, and your file presumably contains 204 (11264-11060) carriage return-linefeed pairs, which when read in text mode are normalized to a single linefeed (`\n`) character.  Use binary mode (`'rb'`) to avoid this conversion.

Comment: In 3.x, the difference can also be caused by the multibyte characters in whatever encoding was used for opening the file.