# Difference in size of a file and its contents

Tags: python

Why is there a difference between size of the file and the size of the bytes object that is returned after reading the file?

```py
print(os.path.getsize(filepath))
```

```py
f=open(filepath,'rb')
contents=f.read()
print(sys.getsizeof(contents))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [file size difference -python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48455460/file-size-difference-python)

Comment: @csabinho That question is not using binary mode and the answer explicitly says that using binary mode would resolve the difference. This question uses binary mode.

Comment: It's a mouse trap :-)

Comment: use len(), not sys.getsizeof

Answer (score 6):

`sys.getsizeof()` returns the size of the allocated memory for `contents`. Note that this returns not just the contents of the file, but also the method headers, the various internal fields in the `bytes` data structure, and so on.

You can demonstrate this with other datatypes. You would expect a simple floating-point number to be 4 or 8 bytes large, but

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(4.5)
24
```

The remaining bytes are the overhead of the data structure's class information and attributes and pointers and method headers and whatnot.

You'll note that `len(contents) == os.path.getsize(filepath)` - the *number of bytes* that the `bytes` object *contains* - is precisely the same, as expected:

```
>>> print(os.path.getsize(filepath))
153
>>> f = open(filepath, 'rb')
>>> contents = f.read()
>>> type(contents)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> sys.getsizeof(contents)
186
>>> len(contents)
153
```

Comment: The additional "overhead" using the floating-pointing number as an example, is because in python everything is an object, right?

Comment: @Raphael yeah, pretty much. Python doesn't really have primitives, per se, or at least, not ones that directly face the programmer.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @Green Cloak Guy

Comment: Thanks @GreenCloakGuy ! I tried the suggested approach using Python 3.5 on Ubuntu 18.04 but there len(contents) always shows exactly 10 bytes less than os.path.getsize(contents). Any ideas on what may be causing this behaviour?